# How to add sub folder to eclipse source folder in project view?

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to create one source folder: "src". in this folder I  want to create two sub folder: one "java" for source and "test" for testing code.

when I want to create sub folder into the "src" folder, the eclipse just flat it in the project view.

Answer (score 2):

You should remove the `src` folder from your classpath, and set the `src/java` as your source folder, `src/test` as your test source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/java"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/test"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
    <!-- the rest of your classpath comes here -->
</classpath>
```

Comment: hi, rekaszeru, thanks for the reply. don't know how to do this, just paste your code in the dot classpath file, the 'src' just disapeard.

Comment: `.classpath` is an eclipse specific file, that can be modified directly (like above), or by right click on the project / any folder inside of it --> **Build Path** --> **Configure Build Path** or **Set as source folder**. The `src` folder is still there, and you can see it in the `Navigator` view for example.